# Get raw string value

Tags: vim

In vim there is the `string()` function, which gets the string value of a function:

```
let a = {'foo':'bar'}
echo string(a)
" => '{'foo':'bar'}'
```

However I have a function where I cannot use this:

```
let obj = {'cmd':"iHello\<cr>World"}
execute 'normal! '.obj.cmd
" => works fine
```

```
execute 'nnoremap a :normal! '.obj.cmd
" => prints 'Hello' when pressing A once, 'HellHelloo\nrld' when pressing A twice. With \n I mean a literal newline.
```

```
execute 'nnoremap a :normal! '.string(obj.cmd)
" => when pressing A, wants to jump to mark H (because of 'H)
```

Is there transformation function to make `nnoremap` interpret `obj.cmd` correctly?

Comment: you want to have literal `hello\<cr>world` or `hello(linebreak)world`?

Comment: I want a linebreak in there. Basically the same that `execute 'normal! '.obj.cmd` does, but executed on pressing A

Comment: that's why I was asking. followed your commands, the `exec 'norm! '.obj.cmd` printed `Hello\<cr>World` here. Literal string.

Comment: Yes you're right. I also see the mistake. It should be `let obj = {'cmd':"(…)"}` (Note the double quotes). But the question actually still stands, because the remap still doesn't do what it is supposed to

Answer (score 1):

Forget `string()` and objects for a moment and just concentrate on those
`:exe`s.

When you use `:normal`, a following `<CR>` will run the command and
not be inserted into the buffer. So if you want to use `:normal`, you
need to escape the `<CR>` with a `<C-V>`. Remember that mappings are
executed as if you typed them.

```
:execute 'nnoremap a :normal! iHello<C-V><CR>world<CR>'
```

Notice the `<CR>` at the end of the string to finish the `:normal`
command.

However, you don't need `:normal` here. It's not accomplishing anything,
and you could do a more straightforward:

```
:execute 'nnoremap b iHello<CR>world'
```